# (Another) ImportError with Flask under mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache2, flask, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

Sorry if this seems like a repeat of several previous questions, but none of those have helped me so far :-/

I have written a Flask app that I am attempting to deploy under mod_wsgi and apache2.

I get the following `ImportError`:

```
[Tue Apr 23 23:46:56 2013] [info] Server built: Dec  9 2012 18:57:18
[Tue Apr 23 23:46:56 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=7445): Initializing Python.
[Tue Apr 23 23:46:56 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=7445): Attach interpreter ''.
[Tue Apr 23 23:47:10 2013] [info] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=7443, process='foo.com', application=''): Loading WSGI script '/Users/admin/Sites/p4p/p4p_jsapp/pfp/pfp.wsgi'.
[Tue Apr 23 23:47:10 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=7443): Target WSGI script '/Users/admin/Sites/p4p/p4p_jsapp/pfp/pfp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Apr 23 23:47:10 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=7443): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/Users/admin/Sites/p4p/p4p_jsapp/pfp/pfp.wsgi'.
[Tue Apr 23 23:47:10 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Apr 23 23:47:10 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Users/admin/Sites/p4p/p4p_jsapp/pfp/pfp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
[Tue Apr 23 23:47:10 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from PfpServer import app as application
[Tue Apr 23 23:47:10 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Users/admin/Sites/p4p/p4p_jsapp/pfp/PfpServer.py", line 4, in <module>
[Tue Apr 23 23:47:10 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     import pandas as pd
[Tue Apr 23 23:47:10 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName  www.foo.com
    ServerAlias foo.com

    DocumentRoot /Users/admin/Sites/p4p/p4p_jsapp/www

    <Directory /Users/admin/Sites/p4p/p4p_jsapp/www>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess foo.com user=admin processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup foo.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /Users/admin/Sites/p4p/p4p_jsapp/pfp/pfp.wsgi

    <Directory /Users/admin/Sites/p4p/p4p_jsapp/pfp>
    WSGIProcessGroup foo.com
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

pfp.wsgi:

```
import sys

activate_this = '/Users/admin/Sites/p4p/p4p_jsapp/foo/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

sys.path.append('/Users/admin/Sites/p4p/p4p_jsapp/pfp')
from PfpServer import app as application
```

PfPServer.py:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import ujson
from flask import Flask, Response, request, render_template
import traceback

app = Flask(__name__)

# ...
```

I have tried using with and without virtualenv to see if that would help, but I get the same error regardless. What's the problem here?

edit: just to make it totally clear, I have pandas installed and the app runs fine locally in the debugger

edit2: ok, the solution was in sys.path - I have installed the latest RC of pandas, which is on a non-standard path, and that's why it didn't work when I simply added the std site-packages path alone:

```
sys.path.append('/Users/admin/dev/pandas/pandas-0.11.0rc1')
sys.path.append('/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

...works - thanks to all!

Comment: where did you install pandas? is that directory in `sys.path`?

Comment: Determine what Python installation and version you are using from command line Python and do the same for under mod_wsgi. http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Installation_In_Use Then in for WSGI application, print out the value of 'pd.__file__' when run from command line. Edit you question and provide the results.

Answer (score -1):

My *guess* will be that apache is running a different Python than the one you're using to test your application.

Comment: WSGIPythonExecutable only existed back in mod_wsgi 1.0. It was removed many years ago. You also can't necessarily just try and point mod_wsgi at a different Python version.

Comment: Funny, I googled how to set the Python executable with mod_wsgi and this came up. Good to know it's not supported - will remove.

Comment: The documentation has 1.X against the directive description.